# Publish angular app as an artifact, what is the path to publish?

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create an azure pipeline that will build an angular app and push it up to azure blob storage. So far I have a pipeline that has the following YAML :

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 14.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 14.x
    checkLatest: true

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Install angular CLI'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install @angular/cli@11.2.10'

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: true

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'

steps:
- script: 'node bundle.js'
  displayName: 'Bundle JS'

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run tests'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run test -- --watch=false --code-coverage'

steps:
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/TESTS-*.xml'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

Now I think I need to publish the built JS files, which are in the root in the elements folder. So I tried this task, but it cant seem to find the elements folder :

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/elements/*'
    ArtifactName: InsuranceCalculatorBuildArtifact
```

What should my PathtoPublish be to find the outputted elements folder?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to copy the /dist folder to artifacts and then publish

given my variables

```
variables:
    projectRoot: 'src'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

Here's what my publish looks like

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy dist to artifacts'
    inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(projectRoot)/dist'
        Contents: '**'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/dist'
        cleanTargetFolder: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        ArtifactName: '$(artifactName)'
```

Comment: Its the '$(projectRoot)/dist' that I am not sure of. Or is it just that, $(projectRoot) ?
If not, I am not sure how to grab the project root?

Comment: My project root is where my package.json is located from the root of my repository.  I use that location for running my npm install command, and then my build command, which outputs to the src/dist folder.  it is a pat from the root in your folder, for me it is only 1 folder deep.

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML has an obvious syntax error that you add too many extra **`steps`** key for each task.

Normally, in one job only has one **`steps`** key, and under the **`steps`** key is the list of the tasks that need to run in the job.

Below is the basic structure of a job in the YAML pipeline:

```yaml
jobs:
- job:
  . . .
  steps:
  - task: task1
  - task: task2
  - task: task3
  . . .
```

To view more details, you can see "[**Job**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#job)" and "[**Steps**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#steps)" in the document about "[**YAML schema reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema)".

In you case, if you want to publish the build artifacts of your app to your Azure storage blobs, you can try using the [**Azure File Copy task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops).

1. If the build step and the publish step are in the same job, that means these steps are running under the working directly on the same agent machine. So you can directly publish the build artifacts from the path where the artifacts generated.

   For example:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: BuildAndPublish
  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Use Node 14.x'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Install angular CLI'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm install'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm build'
    inputs:
      ...

  - script: 'node bundle.js'
    displayName: 'Bundle JS'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm run tests'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: AzureFileCopy@4
    displayName: 'Publush to Azure storage blobs'
    inputs:
      ...
```

2. If the the build step and the publish step are in the different jobs, you can do like as below:

   - In the job where the build step is in, after the build step, use the [**Publish Build Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to publish the build artifacts to Azure Pipelines from the path path where the artifacts generated.
   - In the job where the publish step is in, before the publish step, use the [**Download Build Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to download the build artifacts from Azure Pipelines to a specified path under the working directory of the job.
   - Then use the **Azure File Copy task** to publish the build artifacts from the specified path to your Azure storage blobs.

   For example:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Build
  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Use Node 14.x'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'Install angular CLI'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm install'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm build'
    inputs:
      ...

  - script: 'node bundle.js'
    displayName: 'Bundle JS'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm run tests'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      ...

- job: Publish
  steps:
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    displayName: Download Artifact'
    inputs:
      ...

  - task: AzureFileCopy@4
    displayName: 'Publush to Azure storage blobs'
    inputs:
      ...
```